# Selecting top 10 from indexed field of a big table takes too long

Tags: postgresql, performance, index, explain

I have a table with 165M records like this:

```
Performance
   id        integer
   installs  integer
   hour      timestamp without time zone
```

I also have an index on hour:

```
CREATE INDEX hour_idx
  ON performance
  USING btree
  (hour DESC NULLS LAST);
```

However, select top 10 records ordered by hour takes 6 minutes!

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE  select hour from performance order by hour desc limit 10
```

Returns

```
Limit  (cost=7952135.23..7952135.25 rows=10 width=8) (actual time=376313.958..376313.964 rows=10 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=7952135.23..8368461.00 rows=166530310 width=8) (actual time=376313.957..376313.960 rows=10 loops=1)
        Sort Key: hour
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
        ->  Seq Scan on performance  (cost=0.00..4353475.10 rows=166530310 width=8) (actual time=0.006..327149.828 rows=192330557 loops=1)
Planning time: 0.070 ms
Execution time: 376330.573 ms
```

Why is it taking so long? If there is an index on date field desc - shouldn't it be super quick to retrieve data?

Comment: Does this remain the same after an `VACUUM ANALYZE performance;`?

Comment: I am running it now. still running after 8 minutes. But I am hosting the database on RDS so they should automatically VACUUM

Comment: No, it didn't help. After the VACUUM it is the same result - very slow

Comment: will BRIN index help?

Comment: What happens if you run `select hour from performance order by hour desc nulls last limit 10;`?

Comment: it's super quick! @ yper-trollᵀᴹ

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In your sample code above, the index is explicitly created as `NULLS LAST` and the query is implicitly running `NULLS FIRST` (which is the default for `ORDER BY .. DESC`)  so PostgreSQL would need to re-sort the data if it used the index. As a result the index would actually make the query many times slower than even the (already-slow) table scan.

```
rds-9.6.5 root@db1=> create table performance (id integer, installs integer, hour timestamp without time zone);
CREATE TABLE
Time: 28.100 ms

rds-9.6.5 root@db1=> with generator as (select generate_series(1,166530) i)
[more] - > insert into performance (
[more] ( >   select
[more] ( >     i id,
[more] ( >     (random()*1000)::integer installs,
[more] ( >     (now() - make_interval(secs => i))::timestamp installs
[more] ( >   from generator
[more] ( > );
INSERT 0 166530
Time: 244.872 ms

rds-9.6.5 root@db1=> create index hour_idx
[more] - > on performance
[more] - > using btree
[more] - > (hour desc nulls last);
CREATE INDEX
Time: 67.089 ms

rds-9.6.5 root@db1=> vacuum analyze performance;
VACUUM
Time: 43.552 ms
```

We can add a `WHERE` clause on the hour column so that using the index becomes a good idea - but notice how we *still* need to re-sort the data from the index.

```
rds-9.6.5 root@db1=> explain select hour from performance where hour>now() order by hour desc limit 10;
                                         QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=4.45..4.46 rows=1 width=8)
   ->  Sort  (cost=4.45..4.46 rows=1 width=8)
         Sort Key: hour DESC
         ->  Index Only Scan using hour_idx on performance  (cost=0.42..4.44 rows=1 width=8)
               Index Cond: (hour > now())
(5 rows)

Time: 0.789 ms
```

If we add an explicit `NULLS LAST` to your query then it will use the index as expected.

```
rds-9.6.5 root@db1=> explain select hour from performance order by hour desc NULLS LAST limit 10;
                                          QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.42..0.68 rows=10 width=8)
   ->  Index Only Scan using hour_idx on performance  (cost=0.42..4334.37 rows=166530 width=8)
(2 rows)

Time: 0.526 ms
```

Alternatively, if we drop the (non-default) `NULLS LAST` from your index then the query will use it as expected without modification.

```
rds-9.6.5 root@db1=> drop index hour_idx;
DROP INDEX
Time: 4.124 ms

rds-9.6.5 root@db1=> create index hour_idx
[more] - > on performance
[more] - > using btree
[more] - > (hour desc);
CREATE INDEX
Time: 69.220 ms

rds-9.6.5 root@db1=> explain select hour from performance order by hour desc limit 10;
                                          QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.42..0.68 rows=10 width=8)
   ->  Index Only Scan using hour_idx on performance  (cost=0.42..4334.37 rows=166530 width=8)
(2 rows)

Time: 0.725 ms
```

Note that you can also drop the `DESC` from your index; PostgreSQL can scan indexes both forwards and backwards and on single-column indexes it's generally unnecessary to reverse them.  You only need to be careful about having the right *combination* of order and nulls first/last.

```
rds-9.6.5 root@db1=> drop index hour_idx;
DROP INDEX
Time: 3.837 ms

rds-9.6.5 root@db1=> create index hour_idx
[more] - > on performance
[more] - > using btree
[more] - > (hour);
CREATE INDEX
Time: 94.815 ms

rds-9.6.5 root@db1=> explain select hour from performance order by hour desc limit 10;
                                               QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.42..0.68 rows=10 width=8)
   ->  Index Only Scan Backward using hour_idx on performance  (cost=0.42..4334.37 rows=166530 width=8)
(2 rows)

Time: 0.740 ms
```

Answer (score 2):

If most of your queries intend to select non-NULL values from `hour` then you should consider building a *partial* index on those values, i.e. something like:

```
CREATE INDEX hour_not_null_idx ON performance (hour)
 WHERE hour IS NOT NULL;
```

which, as long as you either query for a particular value of `hour`, as Jeremy demonstrated in his answer, or add `hour IS NOT NULL` to your `WHERE` clause, will give you the same results, and possibly save you a little space as well:

```
# explain select hour from performance where hour > now() order by hour desc limit 10;
 Limit  (cost=0.42..5.30 rows=10 width=8)
   ->  Index Only Scan Backward using hour_not_null_idx on performance  (cost=0.42..8.72 rows=17 width=8)
         Index Cond: (hour > now())
```

If there are no `NULL` values in the column, you should declare it `NOT NULL` (I'm going to assume you know how to do this with ALTER TABLE ;o)), then create the index (without `NULLS LAST`, since it's no longer important anyway). Then you get the same benefit:

```
william=# create index hour_idx on performance using btree ( hour );
CREATE INDEX
william=# explain select hour from performance order by hour desc limit 10;
                                           QUERY PLAN                                               
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.42..0.73 rows=10 width=8)
   ->  Index Only Scan Backward using hour_idx on performance  (cost=0.42..5238.37 rows=166530 width=8)
(2 rows)
```

Comment: I don't have any null values in hour field, Will - does it change your answer?

Comment: No, it's still helpful. Even if you declare the column NOT NULL, the NULLS FIRST / LAST affects whether you get index-only scan or an extra sort step (as Jeremy pointed out)

Comment: Actually, maybe it does. With the column declared `NOT NULL`, if you create the index without any reference to `NULLS` first or last, and likewise make no reference in the query, you'll get the index-only scan every time.